# mousewheel.scroll not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I am working with one-page slide using fullPage.js.

Here is my demo:

http://codepen.io/r0ysy0301/pen/rWKxQB

I create an event when using scroll up or down; button `next` will change position.

Next, I continue created a variable and assign `active` class is a flag to check. If that `active`, change CSS position of button `next`.

But seem it only working with Chrome, I tested on Firefox and not happen anything.

I think problem at event `mousewheel` because I also tested with event `keyup` but it working perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox doesn't recognize `"mousewheel"`. Followings are workouts.

## Use both events in listener

```
$(window).on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

## OR address firefox separately.

```
var mousewheelevt=(/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent))? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel" //FF doesn't recognize mousewheel as of FF3.x

if (document.attachEvent) //if IE (and Opera depending on user setting)
    document.attachEvent("on"+mousewheelevt, function(e){alert('Mouse wheel movement detected!')})
else if (document.addEventListener) //WC3 browsers
    document.addEventListener(mousewheelevt, function(e){alert('Mouse wheel movement detected!')}, false)
```

[Original source](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/onmousewheel.shtml)

Comment: Good answered. . Thanks @TRiNE